# How to access element and elementId from within didInsertElement

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

Using [Ember.CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) I want to access and manipulate the DOM element which is being inserted by each child view. The issue I have is that I don’t know how to get a reference to the element from within `didInsertElement`. Here is [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/nevW2/69/) -- the summery of coffeescript is below:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()
window.App.initialize()

App.Item = Em.View.extend
  didInsertElement: () ->
    console.log ">>> element is: ", this.element

App.items = Em.ArrayController.create()

App.items.set('content',[
    Em.Object.create({title:"AN", id:"item-one"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Epic", id:"item-two"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"View", id:"item-three"})
])

App.EpicView = Ember.CollectionView.extend
  classNames: ['epic-view']
  contentBinding: 'App.items'
  itemViewClass: 'App.Item'
```

`this.element` is undefined. I have also tried calling `element` and that is undefined as well. [According to the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#property_element), there is an element property available inside the view, but I don’t know how to access it, and I am not sure if it is available from within `didInsertElement` or not.

How can I get the id of the DOM element that was just inserted into the view? Ideally, I would like not having to search for it in the DOM since the view should already be aware of what it is inserting into the DOM.

ps: I am using **Ember 1.0pre**

Comment: did you try this.get('element') and this.get('elementId') ?

Comment: yup, that works. I just read in the docs that ember uses get() to access parameters everywhere :p. If you like, add this as an answer so I could accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I wish people who down vote at least would have the courtesy to say how to improve my question. Just because it is a simple thing that I missed doesn’t mean it is a bad question.

Comment: I agree with you, I think stackoverflow should provide an option similar to the one during editing a post to write on the description while down voting ! using 'get' may be a simple thing in ember, but underneath it, lies a concept concerning to how to declare a private variables in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use get('element') or get('elementId') to access properties in Ember